# Angular Jasmine testing - substring remove from number

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have some difficulties in unit testing a function. I'm new in these things and I don't know what I can do.
I have to those 2 if.

Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the `jasmine.createSpy(phoneNumber);`, since this method is under test, we should not spy on it but rather actually call its implementation.

Try the following:

```
it('should remove outside prefix', () => {
  const dialingOptions = {
    reqLongDistPrefix: 10, reqOutsidePrefix: 11, dialLongDistanceLength: 12
  } as any;
  coreSvc.getCCDef = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({ DialingOptions: dialingOptions });
  let phoneNumber = '1011129999';
  // !! Remove the following line !!
  // component.removeOutsidePrefix = jasmine.createSpy(phoneNumber);
  const modifiedPhoneNumber = component.removeOutsidePrefix(phoneNumber);
  // !! below is not a good assertion, you can remove it
  // expect(Object.keys(dialingOptions).length).toBe(3);
  expect(modifiedPhoneNumber).toBe('insert what you expect it to be here');
});
```

Comment: I think you should change the `reqLongDistPrefix` to `'10'` (string of 10) and same thing with `reqOutsidePrefix` because you access `.length` property on these properties and `.length` does not exist on strings. The issue is that most likely the 2 if checks do not pass, you have to simulate the test so the if checks pass and `return phoneNumber.substring` is ran and not `phoneNumber`. Add some `console.log`s outside of the if and inside of the ifs to see the values.

Comment: `.length` does not exist on numbers ***